# How to use a dummy table in Stata

Tags: stata

I would like to have an additional table in Stata, yet maybe there is a way to avoid using it. The problem is the following: I have a table with different firms; now I want to compute for every firm, for instance, the ratio of firm income to mean income over firms in that sector. Every firm has an associated SIC code. So a brute force solution would be `collapse (mean) income, by(SIC)` and then divide income of every company by the corresponding mean from this summary table. Yet I believe there should be a better way.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you give an example of what you want? What is SIC? What does "divide by hands income" mean? (Also, if the question is about how to do something in Stata, it might be considered off-topic for cross-validated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use extended generate (`egen`) to do this:

```
egen double sec_avg_income = mean(firm_income), by(SIC)
gen double ratio = firm_income/sec_avg_income
```

The first line calculates the mean firm income in each sector. The second constructs the ratio of own income to average sector income.